# Webpack plugin parser hook doesn't tap for expression

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for webpack for extracting values from `MyObject.myProperty = 'myValue';` expressions, and my hook doesn't tap for my expression. Here is the example code:

```
var zzz = (function () {
    function zzz() {
        return this;
    }
    zzz.MY_VAR = "My value";
    return zzz;
});
```

Here is how my code for the hook looks like:

```
parser.hooks.expression.for("zzz.MY_VAR").tap("MyPlugin", expr => {
    console.log(expr);
}
```

I also tried:

```
parser.hooks.evaluate.for("AssignmentExpression").tap("MyPlugin", expr => {
    console.log(expr);
}
```

Also without success.

I did some debugging, and find out that for some reason when *JavascriptParser* is calling [getFreeInfoFromVariable()](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/4ea8a435ace96cc6fe5c9b741bc14b68d75624a4/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js#L3583) in [getMemberExpressionInfo()](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/4ea8a435ace96cc6fe5c9b741bc14b68d75624a4/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js#L3605) it returns `undefined`. Because [getVariableInfo()](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/4ea8a435ace96cc6fe5c9b741bc14b68d75624a4/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js#L3503) method return some scope details instead of *VariableInfo* instance or *'string'*.

Am I missing something ? Is it possible to get value of the object's property via parser somehow ? Or maybe there is another way to do it ?